# pProblem with recursion and scope in a function (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

This code is supposed to take a string and return a string with no characters repeated (no "aa", "bb", ""55", etc.). It works through recursion: the function calls itself, refining the string until it has no repetition, but then it returns the original string. I cannot fathom how to fix it. The code is below, sorry if the question is too trivial, but it is not to me. Thank you for your consideration. (and sorry for "hacking" the title formatting)

```
def removeRepetitions(s):
    result=""
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if len(s)!=1 and s[i]==s[i+1]:
            result=s[:i+1]+s[i+2:]
            removeRepetitions(result)
            return result
```

Answer (score 1):

If your indentation is correct then your return value has the incorrect indentation, and you are not assigning the `return` of your recursive function. You also need to assign `result` to `s` at the beginning not the empty string. Your terminal case has to return the single character in `s`:

```
def removeRepetitions(s):
    result = s
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if len(s)!=1 and s[i]==s[i+1]:
            result = removeRepetitions(s[:i+1]+s[i+2:])
    return result

>>> removeRepetitions('Mississippi')
'Misisipi'
```

But you seem to be mixing recursive and iterative solutions, a more recursive solution wouldn't require a `for` loop:

```
def removeRepetitions(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    c, s = s[0], removeRepetitions(s[1:])
    if c == s[0]:
        return s
    return c+s

>>> removeRepetitions('Mississippi')
'Misisipi'
```

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you're missing is return statements to cover all the possibilities.  You also don't need the intermediate variable `result`.  After correcting indentation:

```
def removeRepetitions(s):
    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        if s[i] == s[i+1]:  # found a dup!
            # Assemble a return value by taking everything prior to the
            # duplicate (which is duplicate free) and concatenating the
            # result of removing duplicates from the remainder of the
            # input string, excluding the first of the duplicated chars
            return s[:i] + removeRepetitions(s[i+1:])
    return s  # return input string if we made it through w/o any duplicates

print(removeRepetitions("aaaabccdddeee"))    # => "abcde"
```

Also note that with the final `return` statement, checking `len(s)!=1` is extraneous.